# How to read string, list[int] from file

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, io

I have a text file that has a few lines like this:

```
SK1, 2, 3, 4, 5
SK2, 1, 3, 5, 1
```

I want to read it and store it in a Map[String, List[Int]] but with the code I've written it comes out as Map[String, List[Any]] and I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

```
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Any]] = {

var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[Any]] = Map()
try {
  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
    val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList

    mapBuffer = mapBuffer ++ Map(splitline.head -> splitline.tail)

  }
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => println("There was an exception, please try again.")
}
mapBuffer
}
```

I also tried

```
def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {

var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map()
try {
  for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
    val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList.map(_.toInt)

    mapBuffer = mapBuffer ++ Map(splitline.head -> splitline.tail)

  }
} catch {
  case ex: Exception => println("There was an exception, please try again.")
}
mapBuffer
}
```

but that gives me Map[Any, List[Int]]. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And another Glasgow HND course question. Don't you guys have a study group?

Answer (score 1):

```
def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  // map over lines in file
  Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.map{ line =>
    // split the line into head and tail
    val ::(head, tail) = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
    // convert the tail to Int type
    head -> tail.map(_.toInt)
  }
  .toMap // convert to Map
}
```